# Where is Parse REST API key?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm following this guide on connecting to my Parse server in Flask app. https://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/

I have searched lot of forums but none of them tells where I can find the Parse REST API Key. My config vars doesn't have it. All I can find is, App ID, client key and server URL

Comment: You don't need to specify it. If you want a rest key you should add it together with you master key in the configuration. It is however optional.

Comment: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server#client-key-options   see docs  'client-key options'...

Comment: @RobertRowntree, I read the client-key options part. Just to confirm, since the request doesn't require REST API key anymore, if I had never had a REST API Key before, I wouldn't be able to generate one now. Is that right?

Comment: @cYrixmorten, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I think I found the solution. We can make up random set of characters and name it as REST_API_KEY in our config and use that as the key in our requests.

Comment: @TheMan Exactly, and you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are just connecting to your local server, use whatever you want.

Add it to the file where you got your other IDs.

All the best, and I recommend using [ParsePy](https://github.com/milesrichardson/ParsePy) as that will make working with Parse in Python a lot easier.

Good luck