# ParsePy: Where To Get Rest API Key In Bitnami Parse Image

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-server, bitnami

I am currently trying to connect to my instance of parse-server, created from Bitnami's AWS Parse server image, with the [ParsePy](https://github.com/milesrichardson/ParsePy) python package.

However, the package's `register()` function requires a 'rest_key' parameter, which I believe to be the parse server instance's Rest API key.

I looked for the key in the following file, which came with the image:
`/home/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/server.js`

And only found parameters labelled `masterKey` and `fileKey`. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587523/where-is-parse-rest-api-key), but those answers don't direct me to where I would find the key in a Bitnami parse-server image.

Any guidance would be helpful. Thanks!

Edit: The relevant portions of `server.js` are shared below:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();
var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: "mongodb://root:WcbKujWVdiX2@127.0.0.1:27017/bitnami_parse",
cloud: "./node_modules/parse-server/lib/cloud-code/Parse.Cloud.js",
appId: "APP_ID",
masterKey: "MASTER_KEY",
fileKey: "FILE_KEY",
serverURL: "http://34.242.164.250:80/parse"
});
```

I tried adding a parameter for a restAPIKey before serverURL as follows:

`restAPIKey: "REST_API_KEY"`

But that simply leads to this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/parse_rest/connection.py", line 140, in execute
    response = urlopen(request, timeout=CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Parse.com has shutdown - https://parseplatform.github.io/
```

Comment: can you share the content of `/home/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/server.js` file? Basically, in the same line that it is defining the `masterKey` and the `fileKey`, you can also add `restAPIKey` to define a REST API key.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response Davi! Just posted some of the contents above.

Comment: What happened when you added the parameter `restAPIKey: "REST_API_KEY"` ?

Comment: Just added the error message to the post. It mentions Parse.com having shut down ...? Not sure what to make of that

Comment: I think you are missing this configuration in your client code: `os.environ["PARSE_API_ROOT"] = "http://your_server.com:1337/parse"`

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/milesrichardson/ParsePy#using-with-self-hosted-parse-server